# How to initialize structs that are members of a class in c++98?

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, c++98

The application is written in C++98, and I'm not in position to change it currently. The situation goes like this:

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}

class myClass
{
    public:
        myClass();
        struct foo bar;
        int baz;
};


myClass::myClass() :
bar({0}),
baz(0)
{
    //something else.
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    myClass* thing = new myClass();
    cout << thing.bar.z << endl;  //want a guaranteed zero here.
}
```

The above works, but produces:

```
 warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11.
```

which is fully expectable. I can't do `bar({0})` in the initializer list with c++98. Question remains what is the proper way to do it.

I can think of a couple ways that *will* work - memset, assign values field by field in constructor, assign using default copy constructor of the struct, etc. I don't know which way is considered 'most correct' in this situation though.

Comment: Just currious; why are you stuck with C++98? That must be painful. Is there no way you can fix your problem by moving up to *at least* C++11? C++98 code will still compile with a modern compiler building with a modern C++ standard, so your old code should still work but you could start adding new bits in modern C++.

Comment: Can you add a constructor to `foo`?  That's still C++98.

Comment: Happens all the time, @JesperJuhl I have a bunch of maintenance that sticks me to GCC 3.3 and BCC 4.5. The annoying one is where I'm bound to GCC 4.6. So close, yet so far.

Comment: What about: `myClass::myClass() : bar(foo()), baz(0) {` ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Embedded platform, the cross-compiler has bugs in c++11 mode.

Comment: @user4581301 I really feel for people like you. I'm really happy my team tries to keep up with compiler and standard releases as best we can and modernize the code as we go. We are still stuck on C++14, but looking forward to RedHat releasing devtoolset-7.1 which will fix some issues allowing us to move up to C++17 soon. Really sorry not all shops are like that - you have my condolences.

Comment: @StephenNewell: Nope - struct foo comes from a system library.

Comment: @DimChtz: Compiles, no warnings - seems good.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's not a team thing. It's a corporate thing. Once a product is done, it's crated up and put away until someone finds a bug. Money is rarely allocated to updating old products, but the bugs... They must be fixed. And if you do get a wad of cash, good luck finding a modern C++ compiler for a 20-something year-old embedded system.

Comment: @user4581301 I know exactly where you're comming from. My team tends to go a bit "rogue" though and ignore company/upper-management and just do what makes sense a lot of the time ;-) Sometimes, ignoring management is the right thing (risky sometimes, but still right) to do.